# How to translate email messages body using the I18n gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, rubygems

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1.1 and I am trying to translate email messages body. I created/stated all necessary "things" (YAML files, key/value pairs, ...) to make the I18n gem to work: email messages are sent without problems using the default language (`:en`).

Then I added a new language and made all that had to be done to make the I18n gem to work with another language and to get always a `locale=de` parameter in URLs.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_locale

  def set_locale
    if params[:locale] && I18n.available_locales.include?(params[:locale].to_sym)
      I18n.locale = params[:locale]
    end
  end

  ...
end
```

However when I sent an email, even if the locale is properly set (eg: `locale=de`), sent email message are not translated (those still use the default `:en` language).

**How can I make the I18n to translate email messages body?**

---

- I read the [Localized ActionMailer Templates for Rails](http://blog.andischacke.com/2009/10/localized-actionmailer-templates-for.html) blog post
  but it is old and I have not tested that...
- I read the [Rails I18n and emails](http://frane.offbyte.com/2009/04/07/rails-i18n-and-emails/) blog post and I tested that. It works, but how can handle translation in my case (I am using the `params` method...)? Is there a better solution?

Comment: Hello, i've released a little gem to generate emails from localization files, if you want to give it a try https://github.com/itkin/locale_mailer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Solution

In your railsproject make a mailer (read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html how to make one). For example UserMailer.

```
rails g mailer UserMailer
```

Define a method for example mail_user.

```
def mail_user(user)
    @user = user
    mail(:to => "test example <testuser@testuser.com>", :subject => "hello")
end
```

Now define views. For example: mail_user.de.html.erb and mail_user.en.html.erb. Put your translations in there. If you want to translate variables seperatly use:

```
<%= I18n.t("foo.bar") %>
```

When you do this, ensure you have a en.yml and de.yml translation! Define a translation like the following example:

```
foo:
    bar: hello
```

You should be ready to go.

### How this works

ActionMailer works the following way. You can create mailer models which inherit from ActionMailer::Base. Like ActionController the models have associated views (templates) in the /app/views/ directory.

Now here is the technical part and why this all magicly works. ActionController and ActionMailer default include AbstractController::Rendering directly or indirectly (ActionController::Metal::Rendering). AbstractController::Rendering uses ActionView as default library for its template rendering engine and includes AbstractController::ViewPaths and an instance of I18n proxy to find localized views. To learn more i'd like to refer to the [ActionPack](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actionpack) source code on github.

To get to the point. ActionView allows you to use localisation in your templates: See [Rails guide: Action View Overview](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_view_overview.html) , Chapter Localized views.

Comment: the mailer_name.en.html.erb trick is a great tip!  totally works - where is it documented?

Comment: Go here for some great tips on dealing with email bodies -- http://thepugautomatic.com/2012/07/rails-i18n-tips/

Comment: @cman77 i've updated my anwser, i hope you understand how this works. ;)